# Microsoft Test Manager: Re-running tests in a different sprint?

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

We designed some tests in Microsoft Test Manager for our first sprint (we are using agile) and executed them. Now we are on our second sprint and we need run these tests again as regression. Is there way we can reset the statuses of the tests without destroying the test execution history of the previous sprint?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way. We ended up cloning the test cases into a different plan each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset your test back to the active state:

[image]

This way you know you have to run this tests again in current sprint.

I would only clone test cases if you are going to change them in the next sprint (e.g. add additional steps).

As long as they remain unchanged there is no reason to clone them, from my point of view.

Comment: What if the test does change and I need to clone the test? Is it possible to make these test cases reportable as if they were still the same test case? I have a business requirement of reporting on test case results across suites/plans.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new test suite and add your cases to it.  Each suite keeps the final status of each case within the suite - you can see this in the Test tab.  The overall status of the case (that is, outside of any suite) is whatever the last run was.

I agree that you don't want to clone the cases unless you are changing the actual steps of the cases between sprints.